# MVVM - Where to call function on button click?

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, xamarin, mvvm

So I am a little confused as to how the MVVM architecture can help me and how to use it in this situation:

I am using Xamarin and have created my view and view controller in iOS as an example. I have implemented MVVMLight toolkit as well, and have created my ViewModel for the view and view controller.

I am creating a login screen, so the user inputs their username and password and they are updated in the model through RaisePropertyChanged() events. My question is where I need to call the function to validate this information and actually log them into the system?

I have implemented a RelayCommand that will call a method on the ViewModel whenever the button is clicked as I have seen in other tutorials and such, but I am not sure if I am supposed to call the validation code here.

Some examples of what I have:

LoginViewModel.cs:

```
public class LoginViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _username;
    private string _password;

    public RelayCommand LoginButtonCommand { get; private set; }
    public bool CanExecuteLoginCommand { get; set; }

    public LoginViewModel()
    {
        LoginButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(HandleLoginButtonCommand, () => CanExecuteLoginCommand);
        CanExecuteLoginCommand = true;
    }

    public string Username
    {
        get
        {
            return _username;
        }
        set
        {
            _username = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Username);
        }
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get
        {
            return _password;
        }
        set
        {
            _password = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Password);
        }
    }

    private void HandleLoginButtonCommand()
    {
        CanExecuteLoginCommand = false;

        //Validate login?

        CanExecuteLoginCommand = true;
    }
}
```

LoginViewController.cs:

```
public partial class LoginViewController : UIViewController
{
    private Binding _usernameTextFieldBinding;
    private Binding _passwordTextFieldBinding;
    private LoginViewModel _viewModel;

    public LoginViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {           
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        _viewModel = Application.Locator.Login;

        HideKeyboardHandling(UsernameTextField);
        HideKeyboardHandling(PasswordTextField);

        _usernameTextFieldBinding = this.SetBinding(
            () => _viewModel.Username)
            .ObserveSourceEvent("EditingDidEnd")
            .WhenSourceChanges(() => _viewModel.Username = UsernameTextField.Text);
        _passwordTextFieldBinding = this.SetBinding(
            () => _viewModel.Username)
            .ObserveSourceEvent("EditingDidEnd")
            .WhenSourceChanges(() => _viewModel.Password = PasswordTextField.Text);

        Loginbutton.SetCommand("TouchUpInside", _viewModel.LoginButtonCommand);
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.     
    }

    void HideKeyboardHandling(UITextField textField)
    {
        textField.ShouldReturn = TextField =>
        {
            TextField.ResignFirstResponder();
            return true;
        };

        var gesture = new UITapGestureRecognizer(() => View.EndEditing(true));
        gesture.CancelsTouchesInView = false;
        View.AddGestureRecognizer(gesture);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd put the validation in that viewmodel method.

Comment: Like the call to the database to determine whether its authenticated or not? I guess I should have said authenticate as well as validate

Comment: Because the way I am thinking of it the ViewModel should only handle things that have to do with the view and model, not the business logic

Comment: You could have the viewmodel hand it off to the model, if you've got one.

Comment: I understand that portion I guess my question is about the actual authentication process to determine whether the login was successful. Should that be done in the ViewController in a separate click handler? Or does the ViewModel almost act as the controller and call these methods

Comment: What's a ViewController?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143586/discussion-between-kyle-jensen-and-ed-plunkett).

Comment: Sorry, in the Xamarin iOS application there is a ViewController, similar to a codebehind in many other languages, or like a main. Im just wondering where the business logic layer is in MVVM applications, like the code to actually run the core mechanics of the application, is that done in the ViewModel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on how strict you want to be with Single Responsibility Principle(SPR). Which in turn depends on how complex your application is. The more complex the application is, the more separated the responsibilities should be.

A typical MVVM implementation handles the commands in the ViewModel. And the ViewModel forwards the call into the Model. But his still puts two responsibilities(e.g. presentation and command handling) into a single component, a.k.a the ViewModel.

A more strict approach will be to have the ViewModel only handle presentation logic. Create a separate controller to host all the command handlers. And have the command handlers forward the calls to the Model.

A more relaxed approach will be to simply implement the business logic in the ViewModel. This implies you don't have a business logic layer. Which is fine if your application is simple enough that a business logic layer does not worth the effort.